# How to kill an asynchronous function that is being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a web scraper that's is running in the foreground using Puppeteer. I need to kill puppeteer which is an asynchronous function (NOT THE NODE.JS PROCESS). Why do I need to kill it? Because this web scraping needs to be executed every single day, and I want to kill it just as a way to prevent that for some reason (if still running) the same function is being executed many numbers of times.

Here is my code:

```js
class Webscraping {

   start(){
      this.scrapeWithPuppeteer()
      this.runPuppeteerAgainDaily()
   }

   scrapeWithPuppeteer() {
     // asynchronous code
   }

   runPuppeteerAgainDaily() {
      // I'm usingthe npm package "node-schedule"
      schedule.scheduleJob('5 52 21 * * *', () => {
         // KILL CURRENT this.scrapeWithPuppeteer()
         // and then
         this.scrapeWithPuppeteer()
      }) 
   }
   
  
}

let webscraper = new Webscraping()
webscraping.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

schedule.scheduleJob is part of the **node-schedule** NPM module.

If you look at the docs, https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

You can see that the follow code cancels a scheduled jobs:

```
job.cancel();
```

In other words, keep track of your job so you can cancel it for later with the above function.